# Scalable storage for repositories in Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitolite, nfs

I am deploying Gitlab on AWS EC2. By default, Gitlab uses the instance's file system to store the repositories. However, this wouldn't work if I were to scale it and run multiple instances behind an Elastic LoadBalancer.

My question is, what are the possible options if I wish to use a scalable storage for the repositories? Gitlab docs suggest that a network file system can be used to store files on a separate server. How can I implement something like that on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EBS drive for this.

Comment: I need to support connection to multiple EC2 instances with the storage. I don't think that'd be possible with an EBS volume, would it?

Comment: Not if you want to access it directly. If you want multiple EC2 instance you need to set up one NFS server (with the EBS drive) or use something such as GlusterFS.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, EBS cannot be attached to multiple running instances. It would be like two computers sharing one hard drive. You can use EBS, but you cannot use it directly as the share file system. You need to setup the NFS service yourself. You can follow instruction at http://theredblacktree.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/how-to-setup-a-amazon-aws-ec2-nfs-share/.

Another option you can look into is **AWS Storage Gateway**. It expose a standard iSCSI block disk device interface. There are multiple configurations supported (Gateway cached volume vs Gateway stored Volume). The AWS S3 is used as either the main storage or backup storage in these configurations.